# TYPO3 QuickEdit Page TSconfig

Tags: typo3, tsconfig

I am using TYPO3. By placing "mod.web_layout.QEisDefault = 1" in the Page Tsconfig of the root page, I am supposed to be taken to editing the first content element when I call up a page in the page-tree (so called QuickEdit mode). But it was not the case. What's wrong?

I've tried this in both TYPO3-versions of 7-LTS and 8-LTS. In both cases it did not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure for v7, it may just be broken in this version.

For core v8, the entire quick edit has been removed (moved to compatibility7 extension and thus abandoned from core), so the property does not do anything in v8 anymore.

Looking at the docs it seems the property is still documented in the v8 version of TSconfig reference, this is a bug in this docs branch, it should have been removed.

The TSconfig reference recently got a major overhaul for v9 (currently docs branch "latest") and the property has been removed there. So that is ok.